# Webapp halts when instantiating PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager

Tags: java, tomcat, apache-commons, apache-commons-httpclient

A web service I am working on needs to send incoming json-data to the REST interface of another service. For that purpose, I wrote a little forwarder relying on the Apache project's HttpClient-lib. 
Locally on my machine, forwarding works well, but the Tomcat server running the webapp simply stops as soon as execution reaches the instantiation of `PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager`; i.e. this line:

```
this.cm = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
```

There is no exception thrown or any other output which could help me figure this out.

If someone could provide a few hints for what else to try in order to find the bug I would be very happy.

**EDIT:**

As I found out via remote debugging, the corresponding thread is stopped to prevent a memory leak:

`Stopping thread http-bio-8080-exec-22 to avoid potential memory leaks after a context was stopped.`

I still have no idea why. And I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jstack](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jstack.html) to get the stack traces of your Java process. I would use that to find out which thread hangs, and where. Maybe this gives you a clue what causes your block.